# Problemas com onmouseclick e onmouseover no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código:

Teste JavaScript

```
<script>
    function mudaLampada(tipo){
        if(tipo == 1){
            arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-acesa.jpg";
        }
        if(tipo==2){
            arquivo= "_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg";
        }
        if(tipo == 3){
            arquivo= "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg";
        }
        document.getElementById("luz").src= arquivo;
    }
</script>
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Acenda Lampada</h1>
    <img src="_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg" id="luz"  onmouseover="mudaLampada(1)" onmouseout="mudaLampada(2)" onmouseclick="mudaLampada(3)">
</body>
```

A função funciona para os tipo 1 e 2, porém para o tipo 3 não acontece nada; alguém pode achar o erro? Obrigado.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverFlow Português, faça um tour para aprender mais sobre o SOpt: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa o atributo `onclick` e não `onmouseclick`. Repara ainda que quando clicas e levantas o mouse ele vai passar imediatamente ao estado `onmouseover`.

Para corrigir isso ou usas [o `onmouseenter` (exemplo)](https://jsfiddle.net/xLevgan3/1/) ou cria uma lógica assim:

```
var partida = false;

function mudaLampada(tipo) {
    if (partida) return;
    if (tipo == 1) {
        arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-acesa.jpg";
    } else if (tipo == 2) {
        arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg";
    } else if (tipo == 3) {
        arquivo = "_imagens/lampada-quebrada.jpg";
        partida = true;
    }
    document.getElementById("estado").innerHTML = arquivo;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLevgan3/

Comment: Obrigado, tudo funcionou perfeitamente! Onmouseclick não funciona mais?

Comment: @ErycMasselli o nome [é mesmo `onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click). A microsoft tem [algo com `onmouseclick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx) mas no browser deves usar `onclick`

Answer (score 1):

Troca o onMouseClick, para onClick.

```
<body>
    <h1>Acenda Lampada</h1>
    <img src="_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg" id="luz"  onmouseover="mudaLampada(1)" onmouseout="mudaLampada(2)" onclick="mudaLampada(3)">
</body>
```